# Microsoft Click-Once doesn't work properly under Parallels on Mac?

Tags: macos, clickonce, parallels

I have an application that uses Microsoft's Click-Once to deploy. Works fine on windows based machines but clients using a Parallels instance on Mac have an issue. It installs fine the first time but then never gets updates unless they uninstall and re-install the program.

I imagine it has something to do with the odd location Click-once installs.

Anyone know how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be due to the way spotlight acts. The user was typing the name of the application into spotlight and it found the app, but spotlight finds and calls the EXE directly not the click-once bootstrapper. If the application was ran normally by clicking it's icon everything worked fine.